# VS Code Remote Container unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

- VSCode Version:
  1.62.2
- Local OS Version:
  Windows 10.0.18363
- Reproduces in: Remote - Containers
- Name of Dev Container Definition with Issue:
  /vscode/devcontainers/typescript-node

In our company we use a proxy which terminates the SSL connections. When I now try to start any devcontainer (the workspace is in the WSL2 filesystem), I get the following error message:

```
Installing VS Code Server for commit 3a6960b964327f0e3882ce18fcebd07ed191b316
[2021-11-12T17:01:44.400Z] Start: Downloading VS Code Server
[2021-11-12T17:01:44.400Z] 3a6960b964327f0e3882ce18fcebd07ed191b316 linux-x64 stable 
[2021-11-12T17:01:44.481Z] Stop (81 ms): Downloading VS Code Server
[2021-11-12T17:01:44.499Z] Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1497:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:932:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:706:12)
```

In the dockerfile I copy the company certificates and update them:

```
ADD ./certs /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
RUN update-ca-certificates 2>/dev/null
```

The proxy environment variables are also set correctly. Out of desperation I also tried to disable the certificate check for wget:

`RUN su node -c "echo check_certificate=off >> ~/.wgetrc"`

Even in the devcontainer configuration I have disabled the proxy and the security check for VS code via the settings:

```
// Set *default* container specific settings.json values on container create.
    "settings": {
        "http.proxy": "http://<proxy.url>:8080",
        "http.proxyStrictSSL": false
    },
```

I have tried many other things, like setting NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 as env variable inside the dockerfile, unfortunately without any success. Outside the company network, without the proxy, it works wonderfully.

Maybe one of you has an idea how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

A working if not so nice solution to the problem is to add HTTPS exceptions for the following domains:

https://update.code.visualstudio.com

https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net

A list of common hostnames can be found here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network